# Is there any way to get number out of String and Calculate Sum of the same using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

String e.g. -

```
         10 AL @ 6' X 32' ROOFTOP
          5 AL @ 6' X 32' ROOFTOP
          4 AL @ 6' X 32' ROOFTOP
          6 AL @ 6' X 32' ROOFTOP
```

I need to get extract all the number before AL and calculate sum out of it.

I tried with < sum(substring-before(stringName,' AL') /> but I got NaN as output.

**From comments**:

```
<part_d>
    <description label="Description Part">1 RL @ 4' X 32'</description>
    <description label="Description Part">10 RL @ 4' X 32'</description> 
    <description label="Description Part">5 RL @ 4' X 32'</description> 
    <description label="Description Part">8 RL @ 4' X 32'</description> 
    <description label="Description Part">9 RL @ 4' X 32'</description> 
</part_d>
```

Comment: Please explain in more details which numbers exactly from the string sample you want to extract and sum. And in general, which XSLT processor, which XSLT version do you use? XSLT 2 and 3 with regular expression support by `xsl:analyze-string` or `analyze-string` respectively can easily break up that string and of course then sum components that are numbers.

Comment: Sorry for bad formatting. Tool which I am using supports XSLT 1. Actual string is 10 AL @ 6' X 32' ROOFTOP.  So I need to extract number 10 from that string which is before AL. As there will be multiple strings in same format, so I need to show total number of AL.

Comment: Is it literally just one single string, covering multiple lines, you have? Or the strings all separate, with each being in a different element? It would help if you showed the actual XML the string data was contained in. Thanks!

Comment: '<part_d>
<description label="Description Part">1 RL @ 4' X 32'</description>
<description label="Description Part">10 RL @ 4' X 32'</description>
<description label="Description Part">5 RL @ 4' X 32'</description>
<description label="Description Part">8 RL @ 4' X 32'</description>
<description label="Description Part">9 RL @ 4' X 32'</description>
</part_d>' @TimC

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. Edit your question and add it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum() function in XSLT 1.0 can only sum numbers, not calculations. Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0 (+EXSLT)**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="part_d">
    <xsl:variable name="quantities">
        <xsl:for-each select="description">
            <q>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., ' ')" />
            </q>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <total-quantity>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(exsl:node-set($quantities)/q)" />     
    </total-quantity>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or, if you prefer:

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="part_d">
    <total-quantity>
        <xsl:call-template name="add">
            <xsl:with-param name="items" select="description"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </total-quantity>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="add">
    <xsl:param name="items" select="/.."/>
    <xsl:param name="sum" select="0"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$items">
            <xsl:variable name="item" select="$items[1]" />
            <xsl:variable name="n" select="substring-before($item, ' ')" />
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="add">
                <xsl:with-param name="items" select="$items[position() > 1]"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="sum" select="$sum + $n"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$sum"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @michael.hor257k. XSLT 1.0 (+EXSLT) worked for me.